# What is it called when you classify words into categories, but not by part of speech?

Tags: classification

I'm looking to classify words into type categories like `sushi` to `food`, `baseball` to `sports`, `happy` to `emotions`, `panda` to `animals` etc.

What is this type of classification called? I see lots of NLP-related articles discussing parts-of-speech classifiers. This isn't helpful.

I know any word has many possible categories. For example, `panda` could be classified as `animal`, `mammal`, `Ailuropoda` (it's genus), or even `algorithms` (as in, "Google Panda"). I'm open to any of the above to start. My preference would be colloquial rather than scientific (`panda` to `animal`).

Ideally it would return probability for different categories. For example, `panda` might return `0.8` for `animal` and `0.3` for `bear` and `0.1` for `algorithm`.

Comment: It sounds like "[ontology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science))" is a word that might be relevant -- or, at least, a place to start looking.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the classification you are looking for is called *Semantic field classification* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_field). The sort of algorithm you are looking for falls under the category of *Statistical Semantic*.